# Для чего нужен метод close в классе InputStream?

Tags: java

во многих статьях говорится о том, что всегда следует закрывать потоки ввода/вывода, но для чего это следует делать?
есть ли какие-то ограничения, что будет если никогда не закрывать inputstream/outputstream?

Comment: Для чего это следует делать в статьях же тоже обычно говорится - для освобождения системных ресурсов, завязанных на Stream. Попробуйте, например, в цикле создать `FileInputStream` миллион (может, больше) раз - с определённого момента файлы начнут открываться куда медленнее

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если `InputStream` не закрывать, то в теории ничего фатального не произойдет, ну будут лишние ресурсы болтаться, ну и ладно. Если у вас богато с ними, то можно пережить.

А вот не закрытие `OutputStream` это грозит фатальными последствиями. Самая распространенная история - это недописанный последний буфер.

Классика жанра открываем файл и пишем какую-нибудь туфту, типа:

```
byte[] buffer;
//blah-blah
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File("test.file")) {
fos.write(buffer);
```

Если не закрыть `FileOutputStream`, то с вероятностью 99% последние несколько килобайт (или байт - зависит от ОС) не будут дописаны в файл `test.file`

Метод `OutputStream.close()` - вызывает еще дополнительно метод `flush()` - буквально *смыв* внутреннего буфера - то есть дозаписывает "остатки".

Так что без `close()` будет трудновато (ну если только не делать вместо `close()` все время `flush()`)

Answer (score 0):

Закрытие ранее открытого потока чтения. Метод используется для высвобождения ресурсов, связанных с потоком (таких как дескрипторы открытых файлов). Любые попытки обращения к закрытому потоку приводят к выбрасыванию исключения типа IOException, но повторное закрытие потока эффектов не вызывает. Ключевое это - Метод используется для высвобождения ресурсов, связанных с потоком